# Variable values in haskell

Tags: haskell

Lets say i have

```
data A = B Char Integer
```

and I have a variable called var `in` type `A`.
How can I access the integer value of `var` variable and use it?
Is there any operator to get it? I don't know, something like `var->int` would give me it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a function for this using pattern matching:

```
getIntegerFromA :: A -> Integer
getIntegerFromA (B _ int) = int
```

Though depending on where you want to use it, you can probably get the value using pattern matching right there instead of defining a separate function.

Comment: You can also have Haskell define what are referred to (somewhat confusingly for people coming from OO languages) as "destructors" for you:  change the definition to `data A = B {charval :: Char, intval :: Integer}`.  Now you can use `intval var` to get at it.

Comment: Nitpicking on @geekosaur's useful remark: It's "deconstructor", and the more confusing term to OO people is "constructor" (in OP's example, the `B` is one of potentially many constructors).

Comment: I think using pattern matching somehow makes more sense to me, but thanks for the answers.

Comment: @sepp2k:  Untrue, `B 'c' 5` still works, as does pattern matching against it.  See the heading "Labelled Fields" in the [Online Report](http://haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html "The Haskell 98 Report: Declarations").

Comment: @geekosaur: I think this is more commonly referred to as "record syntax".

Comment: The whole thing is record syntax; the field declarations implicitly define deconstructors.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use "record syntax", which generates the accessor functions automatically, but many people consider ugly and un-Haskell like.